# get the last updated time of variable - java

Tags: java, for-loop, last-modified

I want to get the last updated time of a variable.

```
static Date ti;
for (int i = 0; i <= attachedControllers.length; i++ )
{    ti = null;

    controllers tempc = attachedControllers[i];
     ti = tempc.getLastUpdated(); // return the last updated time of each controllers object.

    System.out.println("last updated of \t" + tempc.getControllerName() +"is \t"+ti);

    Date t2 = new Date();

    System.out.println("Time now \t" + t2);

    long s =    (t2.getTime() - ti.getTime())/(1000 * 60 );

System.out.println("difference is \t"+s);
```

}

the problem is the variable ti stores all previous values of the last updated time of each controllers object. and I want to get the last value only.
the output here is:

```
last updated of     0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:6632is  Sun Jun 21 03:38:59 AST 2015

Time now    Sun Jun 21 03:39:14 AST 2015

difference is   0

last updated of     0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:6633is  Sun Jun 21 03:39:04 AST 2015

Time now    Sun Jun 21 03:39:19 AST 2015

difference is   0

last updated of     0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:6632is  Sun Jun 21 03:38:59 AST 2015

Time now    Sun Jun 21 03:40:14 AST 2015

difference is   1

last updated of     0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:6633is  Sun Jun 21 03:39:04 AST 2015

Time now    Sun Jun 21 03:40:19 AST 2015

difference is   1

last updated of     0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:6632is  Sun Jun 21 03:40:59 AST 2015

Time now    Sun Jun 21 03:41:14 AST 2015

difference is   0

last updated of     0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:6632is  Sun Jun 21 03:38:59 AST 2015 // here it retrieve the first value of last updated time which is my problem.

Time now    Sun Jun 21 03:41:14 AST 2015

difference is   2

last updated of     0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:6633is  Sun Jun 21 03:39:04 AST 2015

Time now    Sun Jun 21 03:41:19 AST 2015

difference is   2
```

I call this this function like this:

```
ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor exec = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
exec.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() 
       {
        public void run() 
          {
            checkControllerHealth ();
          }
       }, 15, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Answer (score 0):

Then put outside of your loop the `System.out.println`. Like this:

```
static Date ti;
for (int i = 0; i <= attachedControllers.length; i++ )
{    ti = null;

    controllers tempc = attachedControllers[i];
     ti = tempc.getLastUpdated(); // return the last updated time of each controllers object.
}

 System.out.println("last updated of \t" + tempc.getControllerName() +"is \t"+ti);

 Date t2 = new Date();

 System.out.println("Time now \t" + t2);

 long s =    (t2.getTime() - ti.getTime())/(1000 * 60 );

 System.out.println("difference is \t"+s);
```

Then it will show only the last iteration that you have in your loop.

I expect it will be helpful for you!

Comment: it does not print any thing :\

Comment: @user1888020 It is given to you some error? Or just don't print anything? Can you provide me a version of your code that could compile please?

Comment: after I add break statement in for loop, the code print the same output that I was written it above,

Comment: @user1888020 Try to enter row by row of your code into the loop and see in which line it prints something and please put a comment again.

Comment: the problem is my code is three eclipse project that related together.

Comment: Mmm... maybe it will be in conflict each other. Are the three projects with the same setup?